# execute list of python files in directory shell script

Tags: bash, shell

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptspy =(
    '/scs/sp1.py',
    '/scs/sp2.py',
    '/scs/sp3.py',
    '/scs/sp4.py',
    '/scs/spweb.py',
    '/scs/sp11.py',
    '/scs/spservice.py',
    ....
)

for i in scriptspy;
  do python3.7 $i;
done
```

My goal is to run a list of files that have python within the directory and not need to run one by one.
individually would be `python3.7 sp1.py`

Obs: I can't execute all .py files in the directory, I need to pass a list to the loop with their name.

Comment: to iterate over the array's elements you need `for i in ${scriptspy[@]}`. Your current code `for i in scriptspy` is iterating over a single string scriptspy.

Comment: @sergio The parameter expansion should be quoted. The array isn't properly defined, though, either: `scriptspy=(/scs/sp1.py /scs/sp2.py /scs/sp3.py /scs/sp4.py)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in /scs/sp[1-4].py; do
    python3.7 "$i"
done
```

I turn on `nullglob` here just in case the files don't exist.

As well, it's good practice to always quote variables.

BTW your array creation and dereferencing syntax is wrong. LMK if you want details.

Comment: In my case I have some scripts inside the directory that I can't execute, because they are dependencies, so I need to pass a list with the name of all of them.

Comment: @JB_ Oh, then just use a more precise glob. I updated the answer. I thought you wanted to run all files with a .py extension.

Comment: Can you do the reverse? Pass the files as I do not want you to run as an exception?

Comment: @JB_ reverse of what, sorry?

Comment: Just one question, in which case do you know if this way the loop waits for python to finish each other?

Comment: reverse, would be what I don't want to run (that's three files only), and in the case I put this as an example, more has script that has no number in front, are all 28 I need to run and three that do not.

Comment: @JB_ I don't totally understand the question but I think you're asking about running in sequence vs in parallel. This solution runs the scripts sequentially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204445/discussion-between-jb-and-wjandrea).

Comment: @wjandrea : Your solution would execute the script in a different order than in the list version of the OP.

Comment: @user1934428 how's that?

Comment: Because your glob pattern expands in alphanumeric order, and we don't know whether this is the order the OP wanted to have. In the concrete example he gave, he wanted for instance `spweb` to be executed before  `sp11`, but after `sp4`. If you would modify your answer to `for f in /scs/sp{[1-4],web,11,service}.py`, it would be more obvious how the OP could keep his original order.

Comment: @user1934428 Ohh, I see what you mean. The question was edited after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply :

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '%s\n' *.py | xargs -n1 python3.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I would get them all done in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel python3.7 ::: sp[1-4].py
```

If you want to see what it would do, without actually doing anything, use:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

If you only want to run them sequentially, one after the other, use:

```
parallel -j1 ...
```

Comment: the vps that will run has only one core, I can't use parallelism

Comment: It doesn't matter, **GNU Parallel** will detect that.

Answer (score -1):

This should run python programs in parallel if shell script is not suppose to wait for all of them to be done

```
declare -a scriptspy=("/scs/sp1.py" "/scs/sp2.py", "/scs/sp3.py","/scs/sp4.py")

for i in "${scriptspy[@]}":
  do (python3.7 "$i" ; echo "script $i done") &
done
```

Comment: This won't run properly. You need to fix the array creation and dereferencing syntax first. LMK when you do and I'll reverse my downvote.

Comment: But doesn't the loop wait for the python script to finish to start the other?

Comment: Loop doesn't wait because you are running python process in back groud

Comment: So what I want to do is not feasible, because it cannot run in parallel, only what is currently in the loop, otherwise it will use 100% machine resources.